# How and when was the name of Somalia written with س in Iran?

Tags: arabic, names, persian, perso-arabic-script

In Arab world Somalia is written with ص. They call it صومال.

But in Iran where people use so many Arabic words in a daily basis without misspelling them, write Somalia with س. They write it سومالی.

How and when did Iranians write the name of Somalia with a س? I think this word and Amman, Capital of Jordan are the only Arabic words that are misspelled in Iran.

Comment: Doesn't the endonym in Somali have /s/ in it?

Comment: Yes, but /s/ sound has three different letters in Arabic and Persian (ث, س, and ص). In Iran all are pronounced as a short /s/ (س). But each of them has distinct sounds in Arabic. ص is a hard /s/. س is a short /s/. ث is in between. Arabic name for Somalia starts with ص, while the Persian name start with a س. Maybe you say that's okay. Iranians just don't want to pronounce a hard /s/! Well, I introduce you to the word صحرا which is started with ص in both Arabic and Persian. Arabs pronounce it with a hard /s/. Iranians pronounce it with a short /s/.

Comment: So what was the reason Iranians wrote the Perso-Arabic name for Somalia as سومالی while there are so many words they use ص in them?

Comment: @SnackExchange "ص is a hard /s/. س is a short /s/. ث is in between" is incorrect (or at best wildly informal and specific to certain vernaculars).  ص is emphatic /sˤ/, س is /s/ and ث is /θ/. This has been true since around the breakup of Proto-Arabic. Somalia begininning with س in Persian is exactly as expected for the word beginning with /s/. The Arabic beginning with ص likely reflects it being borrowed _into arabic_ as tenuis, rather than aspirated

Comment: ص is the _emphatic_ ṣ in Arabic, generally pronounced /sˤ/ (s with pharyngealisation). س is a regular /s/ in Arabic. I don’t know the details of Arabic dialects, but ث is generally transliterated _th_ or _ṯ_, and its standard value is /θ/, which is not an s sound at all. _Sahara_ is an Arabic loan word in Persian – that is, it’s an Arabic word loaned into Persian. Conversely, while _Somalia_ may have entered Persian via Arabic, it is a Somali word, and Somali does not have /sˤ/. So س is the more ‘correct’ letter to use to match the Somali word. Why does Arabic use ص, I wonder..?

Comment: Whether we like it or not, now Arabic is the official language of Somalia. And the official name of the country there is صومال which is the endonym. Iranians have the same alphabet. So they are practically playing with and changing the endonym of the country. If they used a different word (like Deutchland and Germany) that would be better.

Comment: No, صومال is not the endonym. The endonym is Somali, and it is _Soomaaliya_. The Arabic name is a _loan word_ borrowed from Somali and thus an exonym, even if Arabic is now an official language in Somalia. Persian is not playing with or changing the endonym; Arabic is, if anything.

Comment: Use of ص is explicable by reference to the vowel system of Arabic vs. that of S**o**malia, not S**u**malia. Emphatics have a lowering effect on the high vowels. صومال is the best Arabic spelling of the Somali pronunciation of the word "Somali".

Comment: @SnackExchange Arabic is _an_ official language of Somalia, not _the_ official language. Somali is also official

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All foreign names and words with (S) letter which are entered into Persian are written in (س) . If we borrow a word from Arabic, we will write it exactly same as Arabic letters like( ص or ث ) otherwise we just use (س ) for all Persian and Latin words etc.
We Iranians prefer to derive names from Indo-European languages rather than Hamitic and Semitic ones therefore because of this attitude our letters are different from them in the most names.

The Persian name of Somalia is derived from the French Somalie, from the name of the native people Somalis, perhaps from the Cushitic language "dark", referring to their skin color, and perhaps from the phrase soo maal "to go and drink (drinking) milk".It refers to their hospitality with milk; And maybe it is from the name of their tribe's chief that is Samaale .

By the way somal ( صومال ) has different meanings in Arabic which comes from Afro-Asiatic root .

Comment: What about Amman, Capital of Jordan? Arabs write it as عمّان, and Iranians as امّان. I think that's for differentiating between it and the country Oman (عمان). But Arabs write both the same! So why do Iranians change the original name of عمّان? It has a tashdeed that differentiate it from عمان. Also, Iranian امّان can be mistaken for the word for security if written without tashdeed.

Comment: Arabs sometimes don't use a tashdeed. But they don't confuse عمان and عمان because of the rest of the context.

Comment: @SnackExchange, عمّان isn't the original name of that city.  The original name was in Ammonite, not Arabic, and an older spelling would have been  in Phoenician.  But that first letter is ʿayin.  Why does Persian use aleph instead?  Presumably related to the fact that Persian pronounces ع as a glottal stop (/ʔ/) and not a pharyngeal ([ʕ]).

Comment: "By the way somal ( صومال ) has different meanings in Arabic which comes from Afro-Asiatic root ." Can you please tell its meaning?

Comment: This word has two meanings in the Arabic language. First, it is the name of a tree that grows in the desert, and second, it refers to the dryness of the skin that occurs in the desert.